# Arrays, how to add

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to figure out how to add my array list together. So far this is my code.

```
import random  

def main():  

    for counter in range (1, 501):

    num = random.randint(1, 100)  

main()
```

I tried adding total = sum(num) but I get an error. I'm also trying to get the average, but I'm assuming it'll similar to getting the total.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where is your `list`? Which error do you get? Are you trying to calculate the sum or just put them all in a list?

Comment: @SweeneyTodd: obviously, an IndentationError.

Comment: sum(map(lambda x: random.randint(1, 100), range(500)))

Comment: This is not so hard, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `list.append`, and `sum` as you wanted:

```
import random  

def main():  

    array = []
    for counter in range (1, 501):
       num = random.randint(1, 100)
       array.append(num)
    print sum(array)

main()
```

Or if you only need the total, just add them all!

```
total = 0
for counter in range (1, 501):
           total += random.randint(1, 100)
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm reading a basic intro to programming book and everything is just in pseudocode. I had no clue about that append, but it looks like it holds all the numbers so they can be added.

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
import random  

def main():  
    total = 0
    for counter in range (1, 501):
        num = random.randint(1, 100)
        total += num
    print total

main()
```

This adds each of the numbers to `total` and print the total afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy
print numpy.random.randint(1,100,size=500).sum()
```